# Porque no me aparece la opción Recursos / Activadores del proyecto activo

Tags: google-apps-script

cuando en una hoja de calculo voy a Herramientas / Editor de secuencia de comandos, ingrese un código que se me facilito en un video de youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woxWjLrNO-4

Sin embargo, al intentar activarlo mediante Recursos / Activadores del proyecto activo, no se me presenta dicha opcion, sino unicamente me aparecen habilitadas 
1-Bibliotecas
2-Proyecto de Cloud
3-Servicios avanzados

me pueden indicar cual es la razón y como hacer para que me aparezca la opción

gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Lo relativo a los activadores se encuentra en la pestaña `Editar`, no en `Recursos`.

Comment: La razón es que Google la cambió de lugar al que menciona A. Cedano. En otras palabras, la fuente que consultaste está obsoleta.

Answer (score 3):

La opción que mencionas se encuentra en el menú <kbd>`Editar`</kbd>, no en el menú `Recursos`, como se puede ver en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]